# Find the solution of $(xy^2+2x^2y^3)dx+(x^2y-x^3y^2)dy=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the solution of $(xy^2+2x^2y^3)dx+(x^2y-x^3y^2)dy=0$

My attempt: it is of form
$yf_1(xy)dx + xf_2(xy)dy = 0$

Integrating factor = $\frac{1}{Mx-Ny}$

But it is getting complicated. Any easier methd???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(xy^2+2x^2y^3)dx+(x^2y-x^3y^2)dy=0$$

$$(y+2xy^2)dx=(x^2y-x)dy$$

$$y(1+2xy)dx=x(xy-1)dy$$

Substitute $t=yx$ and $t'=y+xy'$

$$3\int \frac {dx} x=\int \frac {(t-1)dt} {t^2}$$

Answer (score 4):

Hint: You can look for an integrating factor of the form $x^my^n$. If you apply exactness condition you will get $m=n=-2$.

Comment: Then you get $d\ln|xy|+2ydx-xdy=0$, how is that directly integrable? Try $m=n=-3$ for better results.